# sage math: simplify algebra expression with steps

Tags: sage

Example:

simplify `2(3x+5)`

step1: `2*3x + 2*5`

step2: `6x + 2*5`

solution: `6x + 10`

I tried sage math: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=ngzkdm

```
sage: x = SR.var('x')
sage: 2*(3*x+5)
6*z + 10
```

can any quide how this can be done

i need to show the steps. of course this a a simple case.

Comment: Unless they've updated it recently, it appears that Sage does not currently support such a feature: https://ask.sagemath.org/question/34991/can-sage-show-step-by-step-solutions/

Answer (score 1):

Searching the web for [ [math software steps](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=math+software+steps) ] or [ [math software show steps](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=math+software+show+steps) ] reveals results such as cymath, mathway, polymathlove, quickmath, symbolab, wolfram alpha, etc.

They seem to be mostly apps and websites; I could not locate
any free software for that task, though it may exist.

That is not SageMath's focus, but one could still give it a go.

Sage has "held expressions":

```py
sage: x = SR.var('x')
sage: a = 3*x + 5
sage: b = SR(2)
sage: expr = a.mul(b, hold=True)
sage: expr
2*(3*x + 5)
```

One can get an expression's operator and operands.

```py
sage: a.operator()
<function add_vararg at 0x...>
sage: a.operands()
[3*x, 5]

sage: expr.operator()
<function mul_vararg at 0x...>
sage: expr.operands()
[3*x + 5, 2]
```

The sum and product symbolic operators are:

```py
sage: plus = sage.symbolic.operators.add_vararg
sage: times = sage.symbolic.operators.mul_vararg

sage: expr.operator() == times
True
sage: a.operator() == plus
True
```

So one could walk the expression tree and
expand any products of sums in it.

Here is a step by step expansion of the simple example
in the question, done by hand:

```py
sage: x = SR.var('x')
sage: a = 3*x + 5
sage: b = SR(2)
sage: expr = a.mul(b, hold=True)
sage: expr
2*(3*x + 5)

sage: d, e = a.operands()
sage: d, e
(3*x, 5)
sage: print(f'{b}*{d} + {b}*{e}')
2*3*x + 2*5
sage: print(f'{b*d} + {b*e}')
6*x + 10
sage: print(b*a)
6*x + 10
```

One could write a function to

- analyse the expression tree
- detect all products one of whose factors is a sum
- ask the user which expansion to perform
- print the steps of the chosen expansion
- repeat

It would involve a lot of trial and error to get it right.
Hopefully the hints above help a little.

Comment: but they are websites, i want to do this more programitically. Do any of these offer open source libraries.